# Parsing Access Field Into Multiple Fields

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an access field called `userInfo` and to the left it **ALWAYS** holds `.` it could be 1 it could be 20, but that is always consistent.  To the right it always holds an `_` in this case **JUST** one.  I tried to use `MID()` function in my query to get the data, but since the number of .'s to the left of the number is variable, this returns inaccurate results.

Example, if `userInfo` contains `.1_` then my parses it appropriately to `1` **BUT** if the field `userInfo` contains `..1_` then the query parses it to `.1` or if the field `userInfo` contains `...1` then the query parses it to `0`

I need a way so that regardless of the number of periods in front of the number it will **ALWAYS** give me the  numeric value.  How would I write that query?

```
Select Val(Mid([tblUserInfo].[fullname],2)) AS usrLvl From tblUserInfo;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

`SELECT Val(Mid([fullname],InStrRev([fullname],".")+1)) AS usrLvl FROM tblUserInfo;`

or

`SELECT Val(Replace([fullname],".","")) AS usrLvl FROM tblUserInfo;`

Comment: Appreciate it!  The first example posted still gives the same result if there are multiple ... then it shows a 0.  The second example using the Replace() statement resolves it perfectly.

Comment: I tested both and get same output for both with example data. First assumes there are no other periods in value. Oh well, as long as you have a solution. If it does resolve issue, please mark answer as accepted.